# Start calculation after the offset in LEAD

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a weird scenario to work on. I have data in the way below.

```
Col1    col2    col3
a        b       201921
a        b       201923
a        b       201924
a        b       201925
a        b       201927
```

Col1 and col2 etc are there for a partition and there are so many columns like those. I have a dynamic parameter which will feed the offset in LEAD function.

What LEAD doing is for every row, it will find the next value based on offset. But what I need is a little different. When the first row finds the offset, the next row should skip the offset number of rows.

For example, `lead of 201921, 1` is `201923`. So, the next calculation should happen from the row which has `201924`. And then `201927` and further.

What I wrote currently is

```
Lead(col3,<dynamic param>,col3) over (partition by col1,col2 order by col3)
```

Is there such a thing to skip rows and continue from the next? I am a bit curious.

Expected output( for offset 1):

```
Col1    col2    col3       col4
a        b       201921    201923
a        b       201923     skip
a        b       201924    201925
a        b       201925     skip
a        b       201927    201927
```

Expected output( for offset 2):

```
Col1    col2    col3       col4
a        b       201921    201924
a        b       201923    skip
a        b       201924    skip
a        b       201925    201925
a        b       201927    201927
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide the desired results *as a table*.  What is the "next calculation"?  It is quite unclear what results you want to produce.

Comment: Perhaps another way of going about this is to calculate the lead(x) value per row then pass through the data again and null out values in col4 that you want to skip. Depending on the shape and formation of data it may be painless to null out every x record's col4. Or you can try to rank order your data to align with your skips and then in an outer query case statement either take the LEAD() value or null based on the derived rank calculated earlier.

Comment: Why does 201927 have that value for col4 in the offset-2 result; shouldn't that (and the following row) be null? And why is it 201927 in either result - are you nvl'ing the last row only or something, since that will always get null for lead? More data and explanation might be helpful.

Comment: @AlexPoole yes, I forgot to add the col3 in the lead. It's the default value argument. If the record is null, it means there is no offset and fetches the same data into the column.

Comment: @user14999956 - so if the offset is 3, the lead for the last three rows in a partition will always be null; so all of those should get the `col3` value? Can `col3` itself ever be null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement using a query determining `COL4` using a `CASE` statement. This will be the base query. `<dynamic param>` is what will need to be replaced with your dymanic parameter.

```sql
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       CASE
           WHEN ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col3) + <dynamic param> >
                COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2)
           THEN
               col3
           WHEN MOD (ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col3), <dynamic param> + 1) = 1
           THEN
               LEAD (col3, <dynamic param>) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col3)
       END    AS col4
  FROM t;
```

Here are examples using the samples you provided

```sql
SQL> --offset of 1
SQL> WITH
  2      t (col1, col2, col3)
  3      AS
  4          (SELECT 'a', 'b', 201921 FROM DUAL
  5           UNION ALL
  6           SELECT 'a', 'b', 201923 FROM DUAL
  7           UNION ALL
  8           SELECT 'a', 'b', 201924 FROM DUAL
  9           UNION ALL
 10           SELECT 'a', 'b', 201925 FROM DUAL
 11           UNION ALL
 12           SELECT 'a', 'b', 201927 FROM DUAL)
 13  SELECT col1,
 14         col2,
 15         col3,
 16         CASE
 17             WHEN ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col3) + 1 >
 18                  COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2)
 19             THEN
 20                 col3
 21             WHEN MOD (ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col3), 1 + 1) = 1
 22             THEN
 23                 LEAD (col3, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col3)
 24         END    AS col4
 25    FROM t;

   COL1    COL2      COL3      COL4
_______ _______ _________ _________
a       b          201921    201923
a       b          201923
a       b          201924    201925
a       b          201925
a       b          201927    201927

SQL> --offset of 2
SQL> WITH
  2      t (col1, col2, col3)
  3      AS
  4          (SELECT 'a', 'b', 201921 FROM DUAL
  5           UNION ALL
  6           SELECT 'a', 'b', 201923 FROM DUAL
  7           UNION ALL
  8           SELECT 'a', 'b', 201924 FROM DUAL
  9           UNION ALL
 10           SELECT 'a', 'b', 201925 FROM DUAL
 11           UNION ALL
 12           SELECT 'a', 'b', 201927 FROM DUAL)
 13  SELECT col1,
 14         col2,
 15         col3,
 16         CASE
 17             WHEN ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col3) + 2 >
 18                  COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2)
 19             THEN
 20                 col3
 21             WHEN MOD (ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col3), 2 + 1) = 1
 22             THEN
 23                 LEAD (col3, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col3)
 24         END    AS col4
 25    FROM t;

   COL1    COL2      COL3      COL4
_______ _______ _________ _________
a       b          201921    201924
a       b          201923
a       b          201924
a       b          201925    201925
a       b          201927    201927
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following your logic, you can use a case expression and analytic `row_number()` calculation to only populate `col4` every *offset* row; something like (with *n* as the dynamic value):

```
select col1, col2, col3,
  case when mod(row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by col3) + n, n + 1) = 0
  then
    lead(col3, n) over (partition by col1, col2 order by col3)
  end as col4
from your_table
order by col1, col2, col3;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6e7abab436c302c5f913c63cf234bf6a)

But that leaves the value in the last row for the partition null. Based on your second example you seem to actually want the last *n* rows to always have their own `col3` value, which you could determine from `lead()` being null and then coalescing:

```
  case when
    mod(row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by col3) + n, n + 1) = 0
    or lead(col3, n) over (partition by col1, col2 order by col3) is null
  then
    coalesce(lead(col3, n) over (partition by col1, col2 order by col3), col3)
  end as col4
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0daf92ec3937d8f596fcc63fd2ca0266)

or using additional case branches:

```
  case when
    lead(col3, n) over (partition by col1, col2 order by col3) is null
  then
    col3
  when
    mod(row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by col3) + n, n + 1) = 0
  then
    lead(col3, n) over (partition by col1, col2 order by col3)
  end as col4
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3b54a9cc0914d2d904909ae4da8e33af)

If `col3` can be nullable then you could always set the last *n* rows in the partition to their `col3` answer instead of checking if the lead is null:

```
  case when
    row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by col3 desc) <= n
  then
    col3
  when
    mod(row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by col3) + n, n + 1) = 0
  then
    lead(col3, n) over (partition by col1, col2 order by col3)
  end as col4
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f06cbbeafff743aaddd4e36fd112b234)

Comment: This may cause issues if `col3` ever contained a null value.

Comment: True, but seems to be what's needed. If `col3` is nullable then I guess it can be decided by another `row_number` to see if it's one of the last *n* rows.

Comment: That's what I had done in my answer :) comparing the row number of that partition to the total count of the partition.

Comment: Right.. yes, variations on a theme *8-)